# How to play video in ios 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

**I need playing a video in my app What I can do? thanks.**
**This is my code.**

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
 NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://nordenmovil.com/urrea/InstalaciondelavaboURREAbaja.mp4"];

       MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
        [moviePlayerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 270)];
        [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
        moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
        [moviePlayerController play];
```

Comment: you write it by yourself!
what is the error? (if it exists)

Comment: I found that this is a possible solution but not work. Only show loading...

Comment: because it's 18mb. Your phone is downloading it. Try with a small one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are trying to play a video from an URL, you can play it using WebView. Here is some sample code (Tested!):

```
 NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://nordenmovil.com/urrea/InstalaciondelavaboURREAbaja.mp4"];

NSURLRequest* requestUrl = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:fileURL];

UIWebView* webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 640)];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
[webView loadRequest:requestUrl];
```

Answer (score 1):

Add property:

```
 @property (nonatomic,strong) MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController;
```

and change your code to:

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://nordenmovil.com/urrea/InstalaciondelavaboURREAbaja.mp4"];
_moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
[_moviePlayerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 270)];
[self.view addSubview:_moviePlayerController.view];
_moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
[_moviePlayerController play];
```

Or use this code:

```
NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://nordenmovil.com/urrea/InstalaciondelavaboURREAbaja.mp4"];
MPMoviePlayerViewController *movieController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:movieController];
[movieController.moviePlayer play];
```